# Countable set of bit strings

Tags: elementary-set-theory

{(w,x)|w,x ∈ Σ$^*$}whereΣ={0,1}

I know that all elements generated by Σ$^*$ is countable. However the set above I believe it is uncountable. I'm trying to prove this by diagonalization by the following way:

Try to list every production of the form described above

let's suppose we have the table below:

0 -> (0)(0) (000)(101) (11)(101) 
1 -> (1)(1) (011)(010) (00)(010) 
2 -> (0)(1) (100)(000) (11)(010)

let's try to create a new entry (n) in this list by flipping the bits of the second set in the diagonal.

n -> (0)(1) (011)(101) (11)(101)

this entry is not in the list because n always differs in its nth digit. Is it an acceptable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's a typo in your question, and you're actually talking about $(\{(w, x): w, x\in\Sigma^*\})^*$, that is, finite strings of pairs of finite binary strings. This set is **countable**, as is every reasonable interpretation of your question. Where your diagonalization fails is: if you try to carry it out for an **infinite** array, you'll wind up with an infinite sequence of pairs, which is *not* an element of the original set.